# Question about wifi on Linux VM

Tags: wifi, virtualbox, kali-linux

I am fairly new to virtual machines, however I have successfully set up a kali Linux machine on my mac running os x El Capitan. My problem seems to be slightly different than all of the other ones I've found while searching for a solution. With my vm, I am using an external wireless usb adapter that I purchased, the Alfa AWUSO36NHR.

Now I have unchecked the "Enable Network Adapter" setting in the VMbox Network settings tab. I have also enabled the USB 2.0 EHCI option so that the VM can find my usb adapter.

While in my VM, I can connect to my wifi and I have internet access but it only lasts for about 5 minutes and then the wifi stops working. The only way I have found to fix this is to disconnect the usb adapter and then reconnect it and the vm connects to the wifi again and I have internet access. I am constantly having to disconnect and reconnect my usb adapter in order to connect to wifi. Does anyone have any ideas about this?

I even got to wondering if maybe its just that I bought a defective usb adapter? any thoughts are greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to disable `fwlps` with the option fwlps=0. Type the following into the terminal:

```
echo "options rtlxxx fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtlxxx.conf
```

change `rtlxxx` with yours

**example**

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Restart your os on VM

Comment: it worked! thank you! if you dont mind, i know this is a pretty noobish question, but can you explain exactly what that command does?

Comment: @gonzato  To disable the sleep feature of the driver you need to set `fwlps=0`